# Working with the Android Calendar

Tags: android

I am trying to add entry to the Android Calendar(2.2),but i have ever got some error.
I tried a lot of test but without success.What is wrong please?
Sorry for my english.

Source code:

```
String calName; 
        String calId = null;
        String[] projection = new String[] { "_id", "name" };
        Uri calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
        Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(calendars, projection, "selected=1", null, null);
        ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
        DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");

        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String timeStr = date.format(time);
        Log.d(TAG, "Value of timeStr: " + timeStr);



        if (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
            calName = managedCursor.getString(managedCursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
            calId = managedCursor.getString(managedCursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            event.put("calendar_id", calId);
            event.put("title", "Event Title");
            event.put("description", "Description");
            event.put("eventLocation", "New York");
            event.put("dtstart", timeStr );
            event.put("dtend", timeStr);
            Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
            Uri url = getContentResolver().insert(eventsUri, event);


            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please post the StackTrace for your error. 
Second: before you try managedCursor.moveToNext, use:

```
managedCursor.moveToFirst();
```

and then

```
while(managedCursor.moveToNext()){ };
```

Comment: I can't post StackTrace because my AVD don't have any calendar,i am testing that on my HTC Desire(if there is any way to install android calendar to AVD or debug project from my phone please tell me that..) and managedCursor.moveToFirst(); and then while(managedCursor.moveToNext()){ }; i have already tried it,but that didn't work

Comment: You ar right, AVD has no calendar. You can debug the application on your phone with Logcat, search for Logcat and Android on Google.